# Only one datanode can run in a multinode Hadoop setup

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to setup a multinode Hadoop cluster. Right now, I am only trying with two nodes. One is NameNode/DataNode (host A), and the other is the second DataNode (host B). The strange thing is that, I can have only one DataNode running, either from host A or host B. If I remove the host B from the conf/slaves file and only keep host A in the set up, the system will use host A as the DataNode. But if I put both host A and B in the conf/slaves file, only host B will show up as the only DataNode in the system.

The following is the log for host A when it does not work:

```
************************************************************/
2013-07-31 10:18:16,074 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: STARTUP_MSG: 
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting DataNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = A.MYDOMAIN.com/192.168.1.129
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 1.0.4
STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-1.0 -r 1393290; compiled by 'hortonfo' on Wed Oct  3 05:13:58 UTC 2012
************************************************************/
2013-07-31 10:18:16,317 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2013-07-31 10:18:16,334 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source MetricsSystem,sub=Stats registered.
2013-07-31 10:18:16,335 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2013-07-31 10:18:16,335 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: DataNode metrics system started
2013-07-31 10:18:16,470 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source ugi registered.
2013-07-31 10:18:16,842 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Registered FSDatasetStatusMBean
2013-07-31 10:18:16,855 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Opened info server at 50010
2013-07-31 10:18:16,858 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Balancing bandwith is 1048576 bytes/s
2013-07-31 10:18:16,932 INFO org.mortbay.log: Logging to org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter(org.mortbay.log) via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog
2013-07-31 10:18:17,038 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: Added global filtersafety (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer$QuotingInputFilter)
2013-07-31 10:18:17,053 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: dfs.webhdfs.enabled = false
2013-07-31 10:18:17,054 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: Port returned by webServer.getConnectors()[0].getLocalPort() before open() is -1. Opening the listener on 50075
2013-07-31 10:18:17,054 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: listener.getLocalPort() returned 50075 webServer.getConnectors()[0].getLocalPort() returned 50075
2013-07-31 10:18:17,054 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: Jetty bound to port 50075
2013-07-31 10:18:17,054 INFO org.mortbay.log: jetty-6.1.26
2013-07-31 10:18:17,437 INFO org.mortbay.log: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:50075
2013-07-31 10:18:17,444 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source jvm registered.
2013-07-31 10:18:17,446 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source DataNode registered.
2013-07-31 10:18:17,786 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Starting SocketReader
2013-07-31 10:18:17,790 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source RpcDetailedActivityForPort50020 registered.
2013-07-31 10:18:17,791 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source RpcActivityForPort50020 registered.
2013-07-31 10:18:17,794 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: dnRegistration = DatanodeRegistration(A.MYDOMAIN.com:50010, storageID=DS-1991287861-192.168.1.129-50010-1373314691613, infoPort=50075, ipcPort=50020)
2013-07-31 10:18:17,817 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Starting asynchronous block report scan
2013-07-31 10:18:17,820 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: DatanodeRegistration(192.168.1.129:50010, storageID=DS-1991287861-192.168.1.129-50010-1373314691613, infoPort=50075, ipcPort=50020)In DataNode.run, data = FSDataset{dirpath='/disk2/clustering/support/hdfs/data/current'}
2013-07-31 10:18:17,824 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server Responder: starting
2013-07-31 10:18:17,825 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server listener on 50020: starting
2013-07-31 10:18:17,827 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 0 on 50020: starting
2013-07-31 10:18:17,827 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: using BLOCKREPORT_INTERVAL of 3600000msec Initial delay: 0msec
2013-07-31 10:18:17,829 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 1 on 50020: starting
2013-07-31 10:18:17,830 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 2 on 50020: starting
2013-07-31 10:18:17,831 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Starting Periodic block scanner.
2013-07-31 10:18:17,831 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Finished asynchronous block report scan in 14ms
2013-07-31 10:18:17,845 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Generated rough (lockless) block report in 12 ms
2013-07-31 10:18:17,848 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Reconciled asynchronous block report against current state in 2 ms
2013-07-31 10:18:20,828 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Reconciled asynchronous block report against current state in 0 ms
2013-07-31 10:18:20,838 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: DataNode is shutting down: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.UnregisteredDatanodeException: Data node 192.168.1.129:50010 is attempting to report storage ID DS-1991287861-192.168.1.129-50010-1373314691613. Node 192.168.1.128:50010 is expected to serve this storage.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getDatanode(FSNamesystem.java:4608)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.processReport(FSNamesystem.java:3460)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.blockReport(NameNode.java:1001)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:563)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1388)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1384)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1382)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1070)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:225)
    at $Proxy5.blockReport(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.offerService(DataNode.java:958)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.run(DataNode.java:1458)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

2013-07-31 10:18:20,839 INFO org.mortbay.log: Stopped SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:50075
2013-07-31 10:18:20,942 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping server on 50020
2013-07-31 10:18:20,943 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 0 on 50020: exiting
2013-07-31 10:18:20,944 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 2 on 50020: exiting
2013-07-31 10:18:20,944 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server listener on 50020
2013-07-31 10:18:20,943 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 1 on 50020: exiting
2013-07-31 10:18:20,945 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.metrics.RpcInstrumentation: shut down
2013-07-31 10:18:20,945 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server Responder
2013-07-31 10:18:20,945 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Waiting for threadgroup to exit, active threads is 1
2013-07-31 10:18:20,945 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: DatanodeRegistration(192.168.1.129:50010, storageID=DS-1991287861-192.168.1.129-50010-1373314691613, infoPort=50075, ipcPort=50020):DataXceiveServer:java.nio.channels.AsynchronousCloseException
    at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:185)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:157)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.accept(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:84)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataXceiverServer.run(DataXceiverServer.java:131)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

2013-07-31 10:18:20,945 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Exiting DataXceiveServer
2013-07-31 10:18:21,905 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataBlockScanner: Exiting DataBlockScanner thread.
2013-07-31 10:18:21,945 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Waiting for threadgroup to exit, active threads is 0
2013-07-31 10:18:22,047 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.FSDatasetAsyncDiskService: Shutting down all async disk service threads...
2013-07-31 10:18:22,048 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.FSDatasetAsyncDiskService: All async disk service threads have been shut down.
2013-07-31 10:18:22,048 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: DatanodeRegistration(192.168.1.129:50010, storageID=DS-1991287861-192.168.1.129-50010-1373314691613, infoPort=50075, ipcPort=50020):Finishing DataNode in: FSDataset{dirpath='/disk2/clustering/support/hdfs/data/current'}
2013-07-31 10:18:22,050 WARN org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.util.MBeans: Hadoop:service=DataNode,name=DataNodeInfo
javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: Hadoop:service=DataNode,name=DataNodeInfo
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1094)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.exclusiveUnregisterMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:415)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.unregisterMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:403)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.unregisterMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:506)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.util.MBeans.unregister(MBeans.java:71)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.unRegisterMXBean(DataNode.java:522)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.shutdown(DataNode.java:737)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.run(DataNode.java:1471)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
2013-07-31 10:18:22,051 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping server on 50020
2013-07-31 10:18:22,051 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.metrics.RpcInstrumentation: shut down
2013-07-31 10:18:22,051 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Waiting for threadgroup to exit, active threads is 0
2013-07-31 10:18:22,051 WARN org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.util.MBeans: Hadoop:service=DataNode,name=FSDatasetState-DS-1991287861-192.168.1.129-50010-1373314691613
javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: Hadoop:service=DataNode,name=FSDatasetState-DS-1991287861-192.168.1.129-50010-1373314691613
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1094)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.exclusiveUnregisterMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:415)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.unregisterMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:403)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.unregisterMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:506)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.util.MBeans.unregister(MBeans.java:71)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.FSDataset.shutdown(FSDataset.java:2067)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.shutdown(DataNode.java:799)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.run(DataNode.java:1471)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
2013-07-31 10:18:22,052 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.FSDatasetAsyncDiskService: AsyncDiskService has already shut down.
2013-07-31 10:18:22,052 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Exiting Datanode
2013-07-31 10:18:22,055 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down DataNode at A.MYDOMAIN.com/192.168.1.129
```

I would appreciate any insights. Thanks.

EDIT: The configuration files are as following:

```
core-site.xml
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.default.name</name>
        <value>hdfs://A.MYDOMAIN.COM:9000</value>
    </property>
</configuration>

hdfs-site.xml
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>2</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
    <value>/disk2/clustering/support/hdfs/data</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
    <value>/disk2/clustering/support/hdfs/name</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>/disk2/clustering/support/hdfs/tmp</value>
</property>
</configuration>

slaves (on host A only, host B is default localhost)
A.MYDOMAIN.COM
B.MYDOMAIN.COM

masters (on host A only, host B is default localhost)
A.MYDOMAIN.COM
```

Update: Just added another host C into the cluster and make host A only serve as the NameNode (not a NameNode/DataNode). And the problem is the same. Only 1 host can run as the DataNode. Any ideas? Many thanks.

Comment: Could you please show me your config files?

Comment: I edited the post and added the configuration files. @Tariq Many thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. Is disk2 a shared drive?

Comment: No, it's local to each host. But these two hosts are VM, so physically the hard drives are all on the same SAN.

Comment: @YellowDuck: A.MYDOMAIN.COM and B.MYDOMAIN.COM should go in the slaves file for Machine-B too. Same for the master in Machine-B, it should have A.MYDOMAIN.COM in it. I'm not sure why are you using localhost in any of the slave or master files?

Comment: @JtheRocker: Just changed them as you suggested. Still, it gave the same error and only 1 DataNode is running. I followed the instruction here: http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/.

Comment: One more thing I can think of is that someone did the automatic home mounting on all these servers, which means I would have the same home folder on all the servers. Not sure if that is messing things up here. By the way, I see no benefits of doing that home mounting thing at all.

Comment: It will be better if each machine has got its own independent disks for hadoop files. If home directory is shared between machines and contain Hadoop files, obviously it's a mess.

Comment: @JtheRocker I agree. So, I put {hadoop home} and everything on each machine's own disk. There is nothing in my home except for the public keys for ssh.

Comment: Make sure you have this in your #Machine-A - Master file { A.MYDOMAIN.COM}, Slave file {A.MYDOMAIN.COM, B.MYDOMAIN.COM}|  #Machinbe-B - Master file {A.MYDOMAIN.COM}, Slave file {A.MYDOMAIN.COM, B.MYDOMAIN.COM}

Comment: Solved this problem, I will post the answer once the system allows me. On a unrelated note, I tried change the masters and slaves file on the DataNode to localhost or the same as NameNode, either case, it works. So, it doesn't seem matter. Do you see this cause any issues? Still many thanks to @JtheRocker. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad that it worked! I have no clue on the localhost. I suppose, in case of cluster configuration a proper hostname for each machine is a better approach.

Comment: Oh..looks like a lot happened over here :). IMHO, it's not mandatory to add the hostnames on slave nodes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved the problem. I read though the error information

```
Node 192.168.1.128:50010 is expected to serve this storage
```

and found that when I copy the set up from one server to another, I also copied the local data dir for HDFS (dfs.data.dir). And this created conflicts. Once I clean the all the data inside the local dfs.data.dir, the DataNode started without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

By any chance did you exclude the slave nodes by adding it to **hosts.exclude** file without a refresh? Or was it excluded previously and you added it later and forgot to refresh the nodes?If that is the case restart the daemons and run **bin/hadoop dfsadmin -refreshNodes**.