# Hadoop data node start failing

Tags: hadoop, nodes, startup, failovercluster

I have a Hadoop cluster of 11 nodes. One node is acting as master node and 10 slave nodes running DATANODE & TASKTRACKERS.
TASK TRACKER is started on all the slave nodes.
DATANODE is only started 6 out of 10 nodes
Below is the log from `/hadoop/logs/...Datanode....log` file.

```
2014-12-03 17:55:05,057 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: STARTUP_MSG: 

/************************************************************

STARTUP_MSG: Starting DataNode

STARTUP_MSG:   host = trans9/192.168.0.16

STARTUP_MSG:   args = []

STARTUP_MSG:   version = 1.2.1

STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-1.2 -r 
1503152; compiled by 'mattf' on Mon Jul 22 15:23:09 PDT 2013

STARTUP_MSG:   java = 1.7.0_65

************************************************************/

2014-12-03 17:55:05,371 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties

2014-12-03 17:55:05,384 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source MetricsSystem,sub=Stats registered.

2014-12-03 17:55:05,385 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).

2014-12-03 17:55:05,385 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: DataNode metrics system started

2014-12-03 17:55:05,776 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source ugi registered.

2014-12-03 17:55:05,789 WARN org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Source name ugi already exists!

2014-12-03 17:55:08,850 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Registered FSDatasetStatusMBean

2014-12-03 17:55:08,865 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Opened data transfer server at 50010

2014-12-03 17:55:08,867 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Balancing bandwith is 1048576 bytes/s

2014-12-03 17:55:08,876 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library

2014-12-03 17:55:08,962 INFO org.mortbay.log: Logging to org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter(org.mortbay.log) via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog

2014-12-03 17:55:09,055 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: Added global filtersafety (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer$QuotingInputFilter)

2014-12-03 17:55:09,068 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: dfs.webhdfs.enabled = false

2014-12-03 17:55:09,068 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: Port returned by webServer.getConnectors()[0].getLocalPort() before open() is -1. Opening the listener on 50075

2014-12-03 17:55:09,068 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: listener.getLocalPort() returned 50075 webServer.getConnectors()[0].getLocalPort() returned 50075

2014-12-03 17:55:09,068 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: Jetty bound to port 50075

2014-12-03 17:55:09,068 INFO org.mortbay.log: jetty-6.1.26

2014-12-03 17:55:09,804 INFO org.mortbay.log: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:50075

2014-12-03 17:55:09,812 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source jvm registered.

2014-12-03 17:55:09,813 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source DataNode registered.

2014-12-03 17:55:09,893 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source RpcDetailedActivityForPort50020 registered.

2014-12-03 17:55:09,894 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source RpcActivityForPort50020 registered.

2014-12-03 17:55:09,895 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Starting SocketReader

2014-12-03 17:55:09,903 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: dnRegistration = DatanodeRegistration(slave9:50010, storageID=DS-551911532-192.168.0.31-50010-1417617118848, infoPort=50075, ipcPort=50020)

2014-12-03 17:55:09,914 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Finished generating blocks being written report for 1 volumes in 0 seconds

2014-12-03 17:55:09,933 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Finished asynchronous block report scan in 5ms

2014-12-03 17:55:09,933 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: DatanodeRegistration(192.168.0.16:50010, storageID=DS-551911532-192.168.0.31-50010-1417617118848, infoPort=50075, ipcPort=50020)In DataNode.run, data = FSDataset{dirpath='/home/ubuntu/hadoop/hadoop-data/dfs/data/current'}

2014-12-03 17:55:09,945 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server Responder: starting

2014-12-03 17:55:09,946 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server listener on 50020: starting

2014-12-03 17:55:09,946 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 0 on 50020: starting

2014-12-03 17:55:09,955 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 1 on 50020: starting

2014-12-03 17:55:09,955 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: using BLOCKREPORT_INTERVAL of 3600000msec Initial delay: 0msec

2014-12-03 17:55:09,959 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 2 on 50020: starting

2014-12-03 17:55:10,140 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: DataNode is shutting down: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.UnregisteredDatanodeException: Data node 192.168.0.16:50010 is attempting to report storage ID DS-551911532-192.168.0.31-50010-1417617118848. Node 192.168.0.14:50010 is expected to serve this storage.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getDatanode(FSNamesystem.java:5049)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.processReport(FSNamesystem.java:3939)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.blockReport(NameNode.java:1095)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:587)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1432)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1428)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1426)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1113)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy3.blockReport(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.offerService(DataNode.java:1084)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.run(DataNode.java:1588)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


2014-12-03 17:55:10,144 INFO org.mortbay.log: Stopped SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:50075

2014-12-03 17:55:10,147 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping server on 50020

2014-12-03 17:55:10,147 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 0 on 50020: exiting

2014-12-03 17:55:10,147 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 1 on 50020: exiting

2014-12-03 17:55:10,147 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 2 on 50020: exiting

2014-12-03 17:55:10,148 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server listener on 50020

2014-12-03 17:55:10,148 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server Responder

2014-12-03 17:55:10,149 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.metrics.RpcInstrumentation: shut down

2014-12-03 17:55:10,149 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: DatanodeRegistration(192.168.0.16:50010, storageID=DS-551911532-192.168.0.31-50010-1417617118848, infoPort=50075, ipcPort=50020):DataXceiveServer:java.nio.channels.AsynchronousCloseException
    at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:205)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:248)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.accept(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataXceiverServer.run(DataXceiverServer.java:132)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


2014-12-03 17:55:10,149 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Exiting DataXceiveServer

2014-12-03 17:55:10,149 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Waiting for threadgroup to exit, active threads is 0

2014-12-03 17:55:10,150 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.FSDatasetAsyncDiskService: Shutting down all async disk service threads...

2014-12-03 17:55:10,151 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.FSDatasetAsyncDiskService: All async disk service threads have been shut down

2014-12-03 17:55:10,151 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: DatanodeRegistration(192.168.0.16:50010, storageID=DS-551911532-192.168.0.31-50010-1417617118848, infoPort=50075, ipcPort=50020):Finishing DataNode in: FSDataset{dirpath='/home/ubuntu/hadoop/hadoop-data/dfs/data/current'}

2014-12-03 17:55:10,152 WARN org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.util.MBeans: Hadoop:service=DataNode,name=DataNodeInfo
javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: Hadoop:service=DataNode,name=DataNodeInfo
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1095)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.exclusiveUnregisterMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:427)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.unregisterMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:415)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.unregisterMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:546)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.util.MBeans.unregister(MBeans.java:71)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.unRegisterMXBean(DataNode.java:586)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.shutdown(DataNode.java:855)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.run(DataNode.java:1601)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2014-12-03 17:55:10,152 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping server on 50020

2014-12-03 17:55:10,152 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.metrics.RpcInstrumentation: shut down

2014-12-03 17:55:10,153 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Waiting for threadgroup to exit, active threads is 0

2014-12-03 17:55:10,153 WARN org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.util.MBeans: Hadoop:service=DataNode,name=FSDatasetState-DS-551911532-192.168.0.31-50010-1417617118848
javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: Hadoop:service=DataNode,name=FSDatasetState-DS-551911532-192.168.0.31-50010-1417617118848
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1095)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.exclusiveUnregisterMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:427)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.unregisterMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:415)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.unregisterMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:546)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.util.MBeans.unregister(MBeans.java:71)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.FSDataset.shutdown(FSDataset.java:2093)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.shutdown(DataNode.java:917)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.run(DataNode.java:1601)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2014-12-03 17:55:10,159 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.FSDatasetAsyncDiskService: AsyncDiskService has already shut down.

2014-12-03 17:55:10,159 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Exiting Datanode

2014-12-03 17:55:10,166 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************

SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down DataNode at trans9/192.168.0.16
************************************************************/
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh, One system for name node and rest of the systems allocated to the data node is not recommendable. I recommend one system for Name node , another for Job Tracker, another system for secondary name node. Rest of the 8 systems should data node is highly recommended.

Come to your question. Format the name node to resolve this problem. Also re open Terminal. some time network also one of the reason.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and suggestion. I'll definitely do that after resolving this issue.                                     I formatted the namenode using command "hadoop namenode -format". Delted my datanode & namenode directories in /hadoop/hdfs/ folder. created these folder again and assigned the 755 permission. Datanode is not starting at all.

Comment: Venu, Can I have your email. I need to ask some Hadoop configuration related question that are not covered under stackoverflow?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to incompatible cluster id problems, so format your datanode directory and start again.

Answer (score 0):

Since your cluster is a tens of nodes, it is fine to have a single node with `Namenode` and `JobTracker`. `Secondary Namenode` should be on the other node as it requires more memory to perform periodic backups.
Coming to your question,
It could be the configuration file copying causing conflits.Same problem [Answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975144/only-one-datanode-can-run-in-a-multinode-hadoop-setup)
And you can try copying the working datanode configuration with the appropriate changes.
If there is no data on the cluster, You can format the namenode, before this stop all the the daemons and then start again.
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The fix would be as follows. This will not cause any data deletion as you would have set replication factor to more than 1. 
The fix would be to check for the services running on the box. In this case, you will have `tasktracker` running on the box. Stop task tracker by running

`hadoop-daemon stop tasktracker`

Once this is done, go to the location you might have mentioned under `dfs.data.dir` property and delete all the files\folders here. Once this is done, run 

`hadoop-daemon start datanode`

`hadoop-daemon start tasktracker`

This should bring up the datanode and the tasktracker. If you are successful in doing this, go to the namenode and run

`hadoop dfsadmin -refreshNodes`